# mgo translation of sort _id : -1

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

in a classic mongodb query i will do a  :

```
.sort("_id":-1)
```

how to do it with mgo ?

```
err := C.Find(bson.M{"Receiver": userId}).Sort("_id":-1).All(&result)
```

is not working

Regards and Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sequence of sort operations is simply translated like this:

In MongoDB query:

```
.sort({"_id:" 1, "name": 1})
```

Using `mgo`:

```
err := C.Find(bson.M{"Receiver": userId}).Sort("_id", "name").All(&result)
```

If any of the sort operations needs to be done in reverse order, you use `-1` in MongoDB query:

```
.sort({"_id:" -1, "name": -1})
```

This is transated to a simple `'-'` sign before the field name in `mgo`:

```
err := C.Find(bson.M{"Receiver": userId}).Sort("-_id", "-name").All(&result)
```

This is documented at [`Query.Sort()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.Sort):

> ```
> func (q *Query) Sort(fields ...string) *Query
> ```
>
> Sort asks the database to order returned documents according to the provided field names. **A field name may be prefixed by - (minus) for it to be sorted in reverse order.**

Answer (score 1):

```
_id: -1 `This mean is reverse in terms of id`
```

Comment: You mean about sort query initially)

Comment: yes of course.  :)